# Jquery Object #<Object> has no method 'getElement'

Tags: javascript, jquery, mootools

I have been trying to use set up this table here. http://www.ajaxblender.com/demos/tables/sortabletable/

I checked with my browser and the page is properly pulling the css and the .js files yet it gives me this error in reference to my sortabletable.js file

(screen shot of the error)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZuTwv.png

Here is a copy of the relevant part of the source code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-US" lang="en-US">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
  <title>Home page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./_common/css/main.css" type="text/css" media="all">

<link href="sortableTable.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="./_common/js/mootools.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="sortableTable.js"></script>


</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
<div id="example">
        <div class="tableFilter">
            <form id="tableFilter" onsubmit="myTable.filter(this.id);     return false;">Filter: 
                <select id="column">
                    <option value="1">Firstname</option>
                    <option value="2">Lastname</option>
                    <option value="3">Department</option>
                    <option value="4">Start Date</option>
                </select>
                <input type="text" id="keyword" />
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                <input type="reset" value="Clear" />
            </form>
      </div>
      <table id="myTable" cellpadding="0" cellpadding="0">
        <thead>
            <th axis="number">ID</th>
            <th axis="string">Firstname</th>
            <th axis="string">Lastname</th>
            <th axis="string">Department</th>
            <th axis="date">Start Date</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr id="1">
                <td class="rightAlign">1</td>
                <td>Sam</td>
                <td>Birch</td>
                <td>Programming</td>
                <td class="rightAlign">01/06/00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="2">
                <td class="rightAlign">2</td>
                <td>George</td>
                <td>Lo</td>
                <td>Support</td>
                <td class="rightAlign">01/07/99</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="3">
                <td class="rightAlign">3</td>
                <td>kevin</td>
                <td>Walker</td>
                <td>Programming</td>
                <td class="rightAlign">01/06/05</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="4">
                <td class="rightAlign">4</td>
                <td>Peter</td>
                <td>Aland</td>
                <td>Project Management</td>
                <td class="rightAlign">23/10/06</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="5">
                <td class="rightAlign">5</td>
                <td>Rachel</td>
                <td>Dickinson</td>
                <td>Design</td>
                <td class="rightAlign">20/01/05</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="6">
                <td class="rightAlign">6</td>
                <td>John</td>
                <td>Tsang</td>
                <td>Support</td>
                <td class="rightAlign">05/10/05</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
      </table>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        var myTable = {};
        window.addEvent('domready', function(){
            myTable = new sortableTable('myTable', {overCls: 'over', onClick: function(){alert(this.id)}});
        });
    </script>
    </div>


</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

any thoughts on what it could be?

Comment: Your screenshot of your error marked in your code reveals use of `$(table)`. You have also tagged your question as using both `jQuery` and `mootools`. Are you sure they are not in conflict with each other over using `$`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$.find('tbody')` to get all descendant `tbody`s and `$.children('tbody')` to get all children `tbody`s. Try this:

```
this.thead = this.table.children('thead');
this.tbody = this.table.children('tbody');
this.tfoot = this.table.children('tfoot');
this.elements = this.table.find('tr');
```

Comment: Sir you are a genius that seems to have solved that issue that lead to this one. I tried replacing this error with .children to see if I would be as lucky once more but it seems this one does not accept the same fix

http://i.imgur.com/x5kGu3W.png

Comment: That error is because `this.tHead` doesn't exist, you mean `this.thead` right? (all lowercase)

Comment: Perfect I forgot the case sensitivity after changing it to this it seems to be loading without a flaw.

    this.thead.children('th').each(function(el,i){

Answer (score 0):

Altough I don't see jQuery being loaded in your HTML sample, your question's title suggests that your are using jQuery in your site. If that's the case, your problem would be that there's a conflict between Mootools and jQuery because both libraries defines the `$` function. To fix the issue, you will have to use [jQuery.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/).